# Как отловить появление скрола в RichEditBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Я решил ограничить ввод RichEditBox его размерами. Было решено отлавливать событие появления скрола в RichEditBox. Есть какой то пример нечто подобного ? Гуглил. Ничего подобного не нашел.

Comment: Возможно дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1179227/373567

Comment: Расскажите, зачем вам это? То, что вам нужно заблокировать любой ввод в контрол, если он переполнен - понятно, а зачем? Это не типичный сценарий, и "из коробки" в UWP он не поддерживается. Возможно, вам потребуется реализация своего собственного шаблона для контрола, или даже своего собственного контрола.

Comment: @aepot Мне нужно разбить текст на страницы. Как в редакторе word например. Сожалению я не могу использовать готовые платные аналоги. Потому при условии появлении скрола я планировал отправлять часть текста на следующий RichEditBox.

Comment: Вот теперь понятно, что вы хотите получить, это же можно было сразу указать в вопросе, верно? Не все так просто оказалось, но вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52885614/12888024).

Comment: @aepot. Да, вы правы. Я слабо описал проблему. Спасибо за помощь.